# Cannot start postgres service because expected file is not in run directory

Tags: arch-linux, systemd, postgresql

I recently tried to install postgres on my arch machine. I was able to run the `initdb` command as the postgres user, but I cannot actually run the service. This is what I see in my terminal when I try to run the db:

```bash
insomnia@the-void ~/p/lemmy (main)> su - postgres -c "pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgres/data -l logfile start"
Password: 
waiting for server to start.... stopped waiting
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
insomnia@the-void ~/p/lemmy (main) [1]> cat logfile
2023-05-11 06:31:05.607 EDT [6545] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 12.2.1 20230211, 64-bit
2023-05-11 06:31:05.607 EDT [6545] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 5432
2023-05-11 06:31:05.607 EDT [6545] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2023-05-11 06:31:05.609 EDT [6545] FATAL:  could not create lock file "/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock": No such file or directory
2023-05-11 06:31:05.611 EDT [6545] LOG:  database system is shut down
2023-05-11 06:37:28.083 EDT [7218] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 12.2.1 20230211, 64-bit
2023-05-11 06:37:28.083 EDT [7218] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 5432
2023-05-11 06:37:28.083 EDT [7218] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2023-05-11 06:37:28.085 EDT [7218] FATAL:  could not create lock file "/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock": No such file or directory
2023-05-11 06:37:28.087 EDT [7218] LOG:  database system is shut down
2023-05-11 06:38:39.659 EDT [7363] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 12.2.1 20230211, 64-bit
2023-05-11 06:38:39.660 EDT [7363] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 5432
2023-05-11 06:38:39.660 EDT [7363] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2023-05-11 06:38:39.662 EDT [7363] FATAL:  could not create lock file "/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock": No such file or directory
2023-05-11 06:38:39.666 EDT [7363] LOG:  database system is shut down
2023-05-11 06:38:53.104 EDT [7430] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 15.2 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 12.2.1 20230211, 64-bit
2023-05-11 06:38:53.105 EDT [7430] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 5432
2023-05-11 06:38:53.105 EDT [7430] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2023-05-11 06:38:53.106 EDT [7430] FATAL:  could not create lock file "/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432.lock": No such file or directory
2023-05-11 06:38:53.108 EDT [7430] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

I checked the run directory and, just like was said in the logs, there is nothing for postgres there:

```bash
insomnia@the-void ~/p/lemmy (main)> ls -a /run
./       containerd/   dbus/             docker/       faillock/   log/    mount/           nvidia-xdriver-d8991f8f=  samba/  systemd/     udev/     utmp
../      credentials/  dmeventd-client|  docker.pid    initramfs/  lvm/    NetworkManager/  openvpn-client/           sddm/   tmpfiles.d/  udisks2/  xtables.lock
clamav/  cups/         dmeventd-server|  docker.sock=  lock/       media/  nscd/            openvpn-server/           sudo/   tpm2-tss/    user/
insomnia@the-void ~/p/lemmy (main)> ls -a /run | grep postgresql
insomnia@the-void ~/p/lemmy (main) [0|1]>
```

How do I make sure the expected directories/files are in /run?

Answer (score 1):

You fell in a trap!  The [Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Postgres) text itself does not say to use `pg_ctl start`.  Instead, it says:

> Finally, [start](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Help:Reading#Control_of_systemd_units) and [enable](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Help:Reading#Control_of_systemd_units) the postgresql.service

The linked words say:

> ### Control of systemd units
>
> When an article invites to start, enable, stop or restart some systemd units (e.g. a service), it will not indicate the detailed instructions to do so, but instead you will read something like:
>
> > Start example.service
>
> This means that you have to run:
>
> ```
> # systemctl start example.service
> ```
>
> The [systemd](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Systemd) article contains all the detailed explanations to interact with systemd units in Arch Linux proficiently.

To start and enable postgresql:

```
systemctl enable postgresql
systemctl start postgresql
```

This will use the system service definition.  We might guess this knows how to create `/run/postgresql/`.

Since Arch uses systemd, it will ensure postgresql is started directly by [PID 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/init).  It will avoid accidentally inheriting any special custom environment you may have in your terminal.  Nice and clean.